# React-router links not working when nested in child pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need the following structure in my application,
Login ->  Dashboard ,with the following side menus

1..Test List    -> URL must be /dashboard/testlist
2. User List      -> URl must be /dashboard/userlist

UserList should be selected by default and details page should show on the right panel.

When I click on any item in the Userlist it should show another menus

1. User Info  -> URL must be /dashboard/testlist/userinfo
2. User friends-> URl must be /dashboard/testlist/userinfo

I have designed following structure for routing  and when we click on the links the URL changing but the page is not loaded
Codesandbox link as follows https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-sidebar-forked-3jwcs?file=/example.js

I can make this work by adding URL  params in the dashboard route as follows

```
<Route
          exact
          path="/dashboard/:path?"
          component={DashboardPage}
        />
```

but it will need more URL params when more nesting requires in the child pages. Some help, please